# get value from manual grains doesn't work currently

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

trying to get Grains value in Jinja template but i dont know how to get it to work..

i'm traing to get fqdn and manually added grain (appfqdn)

here is the jinja

```
{%- set SERVERNAME = grains['fqdn'] -%}
{%- set APPTIER = grains['appfqdn'] -%}
```

the result of first line work very well. i get the fqdn of the server.

2nd one doesn't. i got it like this: [u'client02.lab.home']

as you can see there is u and ' and []

not sure how to grab it correctly.

also when i grab the value on salt master manfully with json format output. this is hop i get it.

salt 'client03.lab.home' grains.item fqdn --out json

```
{
    "client03.lab.home": {
        "fqdn": "client03.lab.home"
    }
}
```

salt 'client03.lab.home' grains.item appfqdn --out json

```
{
    "client03.lab.home": {
        "appfqdn": [
            "client02.lab.home"
        ]
    }
}
```

not sure how to use jinja to get the value correctly without the single quot, the u and brackets..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the the solution.

```
{%- set APPTIER = grains['appfqdn'][0] -%}
```

was able to to get the right result.

Comment: It's because `appfqdn` is a list with one item, while `fqdn` is just a key value pair.